# Compare two arrays and add the new values to second array based on first array ID Angualr

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi  i m trying to loop over two arrays and finding the id and fieldId for each respectively, I need to construct an arrayB with documentId and new values, based on arrayA Id's
For example: if arrayA has three Ids (1,2,3) and arrayB has two fieldId(1,3) then result should be arrayB = ([documentID,yes,no,yes],[documentID,no,no,yes]). in the arrayB first value should be documentId and remain should be values based on ID  of arrayA

Below is the arrayA and arrayB:-

```js
let arrayA = [{
    id: 13896,
    localeData: [],
    mnemonicCode: "FILD_NONIND_LNAM"

  },
  {
    id: 13899,
    localeData: [],
    mnemonicCode: "FILD_NONIND_LNAM"

  },
  {
    id: 13900,
    localeData: [],
    mnemonicCode: "FILD_NONIND_LNAM"

  },
  {
    id: 13919,
    localeData: [],
    mnemonicCode: "FILD_NONIND_LNAM"

  },




]

let arrayB = [{
    documentId: 13990,
    localeData: [],
    fieldId: 13900,
    mnemonicCode: "FILD_NONIND_LNAM"

  },
  {
    documentId: 13990,
    localeData: [],
    fieldId: 13919,
    mnemonicCode: "FILD_NONIND_LNAM"

  },
  {
    documentId: 14004,
    localeData: [],
    fieldId: 13900,
    mnemonicCode: "FILD_NONIND_LNAM"

  },
  {
    documentId: 14004,
    localeData: [],
    fieldId: 13899,
    mnemonicCode: "FILD_NONIND_LNAM"

  }
]
```

above is the two arrays in which arrayA has id and arrayB has FieldId and DocumentId

Below is the result :-

```js
let result = [
  [
    new MetaCheckbox({
      documentId: 13990,
      checked: false,
    }),
    new MetaLabel({
      fieldId: 13896
    }),
    new MetaLabel({
      fieldId: 13899
    }),
    new MetaCheckbox({
      checked: true,
      fieldId: 13900
    }),
    new MetaCheckbox({
      checked: true,
      fieldId: 13919
    }),

  ],
  [
    new MetaCheckbox({
      documentId: 14004,
      checked: false,
    }),
    new MetaLabel({
      fieldId: 13896
    }),
    new MetaCheckbox({
      checked: true,
      fieldId: 13899
    }),
    new MetaCheckbox({
      checked: true,
      fieldId: 13900
    }),
    new MetaLabel({
      fieldId: 13919
    })

  ],
]
```

below is the function which i have tried but no result has the functionality is giving values yes or no in ArrayA instead arrayB i tried multiple way though not found any solution

Here is the try error solution:

```js
const filteredFields = metaField[0].th.map((item) => {
  let result = metaField[0].tr.filter(
    (loc) => loc.fieldId == item.id
  );
  if (temp.length) {
    documentData.push(
      new MetaCheckbox({
        label: "yes",
        checked: false,
        localeCode: "abc",
      }),
      new MetaCheckbox({
        label: "yes",
        checked: true,
        labelPosition: "before",
      })
    );
  } else {
    documentData.push(
      new MetaLabel({
        label: "no",
      })
    );
  }
  return result = documentData
});


console.log(filteredFields);
```

Please help me with this solution thanks

Comment: I'm unable to understand the question. Please go through the problem statement and formulate it again. Also, you're trying to construct an array with name `arrayB` but it's already present. I might've inferred this wrong but the question statement is too complex.

Comment: i ll make it little simple  arrayA has three Ids (1,2,3) and arrayB has two fieldId(1,3), where the fieldId from arrayB matches with ArrayA then mark tht has yes else no ex: result should be Result(yes,no,yes), in result first is 'yes' because both array has id 1 and second element is 'no' because arrayA has 2 but arrayB doesnt contain 2. and also also in arrayB first element i want to push some name at first element of id ex: result(name, yes(1), no , yes(3))
i hope this helps

Comment: Yes, this helps. But, what is metaField? I suggest you provide us a minimal reproducible example so that we can get more clarity on what issue are you facing.